# How to make accordion menu expand smoother?

Tags: 7, navigation

I installed [accordion menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/accordion_menu) on Drupal 7. The menu work perfectly fine but it does not expand that smooth. How can I make it smoother? How do I replace JavaScript to on module?

**Note**: I tried slide and bounceslide. they are not smooth at all. The animation option say ("bounceslide" requires UI Effects Core)". Is there something I need to enable?

Comment: Have you tried playing with the animation settings on the accordion menu block settings?

Comment: i tried slide and bounceslide. they are not smooth at all. The animation option say ("bounceslide" requires UI Effects Core)". Is there something I need to enable?

Comment: Please check https://jqueryui.com/accordion/ Here you will several option to make accordion better. Use view source to get jquery code and similar in your customjs. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend updating your jQuery version using the [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module  and enabling the module [jQuery UI theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/jqueryui_theme) to have smoother effects. I think this is what you need for the UI Effects Core.